# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand when using hashlib

Tags: python

I am making a home assistant in python as my next step in learning python. The login converts an entered password into hash. The hashed password is then stored into a separate text file. I get this error message later on in my program when I check to see if the passwords match during login. The exact error message is "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not _hashlib.HASH". Any help would be GREAT. I have been trying to figure this out for the last three hours. Thank you!

Account creation phase:

```
     password = input("Enter a password: ")
    password1 = input("Please reenter your password: ")
    if password1 == password:
        print("Thank you for creating an account!")
        with open("passwords.txt", "a")as f:
            hashed_password_object = hashlib.md5(str.encode(password))
            f.write(hashed_password_object.hexdigest())
            str(f)
```

Login phase:

```
    login_password = input("Please enter your password: ")
login_password1 = hashlib.md5(str.encode(login_password))
login_password1.hexdigest()
str(login_password1)
with open('passwords.txt') as e:
    if login_password1 in e.read():
        print("Login successful. Welcome to your personal home assistant, 
    JIM.")
    elif login_password1 is not e.read():
        print("You got your password wrong you idiot.")
```

Comment: `login_password1.hexdigest()` doesn't modify `login_password1`. you need to assign the return value of the function to a variable and use that variable instead.

Comment: Also `str(variable)` on its own doesn't change the type of `variable` going forward. Something like `variable_str = str(variable)` would be needed.